# Redirect clients based on MAC address - OpenWRT/LEDE

Tags: iptables, firewall, proxy, redirect, openwrt

on OpenWRT (LEDE) router I have the following redirection:

```
config redirect
    option proto 'tcp'
    option target 'DNAT'
    option dest 'lan'
    option _name 'Proxy for HTTP'
    option src 'lan'
    option dest_port '3128'
    option src_dport '443'
    option dest_ip '192.168.155.1'
    option src_dip '!192.168.155.1'
    list src_mac '!XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'
    list src_mac '!XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'
```

This code redirects all the clients to the proxy server. The redirection works fine. But I would like to add some devices by MAC address should not be redirected to proxy. In the above code if there is only one MAC address then it works but if there are more than one it does not and the devices with listed MAC addresses are redirected to proxy. The MAC addresses are correct so it can't be the problem I think.

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

If you need more detailed information please ask.

Comment: I suspect when you add multiple, they both filter the other corresponding MAC address from the `list src_mac '!XXX'` entries.